# JSON schema - contains const error message

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In any of the JSON schema draft versions, is there an official way in the spec for what error message shows when a `contains` `const` is missing in `allOf`?

Take this for example.  In most validation tools I've tried, it says something like "should be equal to constant" or "does not match constant" for `name` `A`, `C`, and `D` (despite `A` being another `const` in the schema).  I just want the error to output something like "Missing const B at #/allOf/1/contains/properties/name/const".  Using this example, I don't care if there are other names in there, just as long as one of them is "A" and another one is "B".

Schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "const": "A"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "const": "B"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON

```json
[
  {
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "name": "C"
  },
  {
    "name": "D"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Error messaging is not defined by the specification.  Mostly, this is due to

- figuring out how to handle localization is hard, and
- giving implementations the freedom to determine their own wording is important to us

There *is* an [output format](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.12), however, as well as an [effort to update it](https://github.com/orgs/json-schema-org/discussions/63).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is there a better way to define the schema in this case?  "A" and "B" are required "name", but anything else is also allowed.

Comment: The way you have your schema set up is ideal.